# Che cos'è un "pintone"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel racconto *Un giorno di fuoco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Poi la zia ci chiamò a mangiare. Mio ziastro disse subito, nell’atto di sedersi: – Oggi mi sento piú di bere che di mangiare. – Il vino è tutto qui, – disse lei, alzando il **pintone** controluce.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato del vocabolo "pintone"? Non sono riuscita a trovarlo in nessun dizionario.

Comment: È evidentemente un accrescitivo "scherzoso" di "_pinta_" che è un'unità di misura per i liquidi. (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinta_(unit%C3%A0_di_misura)) sta a indicare probabilmente il fiasco di vino.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: La "pinta" veniva usata nel Piemonte?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Addesso ricordo di essere stata in un ristorante a Saluzzo dove il vino si vendeva a "bicer" e "pintun" (https://www.legart.it/piemontese/misure.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il [pintone](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=PINTONE100) in Piemonte è un bottiglione da due litri:

> regionale nell'uso piemontese: bottiglione da due litri, specialmente
>   utilizzato per il vino.

E da Wikipedia alla voce [bottiglione](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottiglione):

> La parola bottiglione ebbe origine nel XVI secolo. Un termine molto
>   comune in Piemonte per indicare il bottiglione è **pintone** (dal
>   piemontese pinton - pronuncia: pintun). La parola è utilizzata nelle
>   opere di vari scrittori tra i quali Primo Levi e Beppe Fenoglio. Un
>   altro termine per indicare il bottiglione è doppiolitro o anche doppio
>   litro.